# How to create real time application for Log Analysis

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-forwarder

I am new to Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana by using this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-and-visualize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04)  i just played around it. Now I want to know how to create real production application for Log Analysis including login and securities model. Is there any way to achieve with kibana.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly vague question, but...

In Kibana 3, you setup dashboards that are made up of "panels".  Each panel can be a different type (histogram, pie chart, etc).  Each panel can chart one or more queries.

In Kibana 4 (still in beta), it's a more explicit multi-step process.  You create "visualizations", which, like panels, are components that you'll use in dashboards.

Comment: Yeah, we can create panels in Kibana but my questions how to create real production application using Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana.

Comment: You ship the logs to logstash, process them, insert them into elasticsearch, and build dashboard of interesting things with kibana.  That's what everyone does for "real production application[s]".

Comment: Thanks.What about login functionality is there any way to  do with Kibana.

Comment: I've not done user auth, but I've seen people use nginx proxies to better control kibana access to elasticsearch.  Also see the upcoming 'shield' project from elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you. I think shield is best choice.